# WIX Toolset Bundle get parent directory of path returned from ComponentSearch

Tags: wix, wix3

I am attempting to have my WIX bundle use the previous install directory if an earlier version is already installed.  The previous versions did not create a registry entry for the install location.   As such I tried to use a ComponentSearch (Util Extension) to find the main executable.  The install directory is the parent directory of the directory containing the executable.  The ComponentSearch gives me the directory C:\InstallDirectory\DirectoryContainingEXE.  How can I get C:\InstallDirectory?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
         xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Fragment>
    <util:ComponentSearch Id="ExeComponentSearch" Guid="{COMPONENT GUID}" Result="directory" Variable="InstallFolder"/>
  </Fragment>
</Include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  The obvious solution is to use a file whose parent is the C:\InstallDirectory.  Since I don't have any files in the C:|InstallDirectory that would not work.  What I did have is a component that sets permissions on the C:\InstallDirectory.  I used that component to get the directory.  This would probably work with other types of components that do not contain a file.  Maybe a registry that is the key path of the component?

```
<util:ComponentSearch Id="InstallDirectoryPermissionsSearch" Guid="{COMPONENT GUID}" Result="directory"  Variable="InstallFolder"/>
```